# CloudWatch insights log parsing

Tags: regex, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have been trying to parse the resource arn ex.(arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:0123456789:volume/vol-gg4gggs0svevb3000) to extract the vol-* on CloudWatch logs insights and unable to get the regex pattern right with desired result.

I have tried using below pattern but no result.

```
parse @message /.[v,o,l].-([0-9][a-z]){0,17}/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pattern that you tried, this part `([0-9][a-z]){0,17}` repeats 0 to 17 times a single digit, immediately followed by a single char a-z. The maximum number of chars is therefore 34 in that particular order.

Also note that when repeating a capture group, the group value contains the value of the last iteration. In this case that will be 2 characters.

This part `.[v,o,l].` can be written as `.[vol,].` and matches 3 chars: a dot which can match any char except a newline, then 1 of either `v` `o` `l` or `,` because it is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and again a dot that can match any char except a newline

Reading [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html), the parts that you want to extract should be in a named capture group.

```
parse @message /(?<volume>vol-[0-9a-z]{17})/
```

The pattern matches

- `(?<volume>` Named capture group `volume`

  - `vol-` Match literally
  - `[0-9a-z]{17}` Repeat 17 times any of the listed in the character class
- `)` Close named group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4KSqdB/1)

Comment: Thank you so much. that worked. I'm also trying to merge two queries based a common column  but I haven't find anywhere in  the document  you mentioned or any source that I can. Any clue about it?. Thanks again

Comment: About the question of the merging of 2 columns, unfortunately I don't have an answer to that, but you could always consider posting a new question.

Comment: Sure. Thanks much